# How can I pass Json data to autocomplete sourece variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

How can I pass Json data to autocomplete source variable. I have the json data in grid variable `gridModel(sjg struts tag element)`

```
        $( "#searchText" ).autocomplete({
        source: "here what should I pass"
    });
```

or any other way to get the json data call any ajax call not needed??

Answer (score 0):

The datasource is a server-side script which returns JSON data, specified via a simple URL for the source-option.

Please visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote for more information on how to pass source information.

Here is an example:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
       source: "url to call the server that returns json"
}
});
```